# sql query order by parts of

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

lets say you have a table with 10 000 records of different email adresses, but within this tables there are a few hundred (this can vary and should not matter) addresses that contains a specific domain name ie @horses.com.

I would like **in one single query** retrieve all 10 000 record, but the ones that contains @horses.com will always be on top of the list.

Something like this " SELECT TOP 10000 * FROM dbo.Emails ORDER BY -- the records that contains @horses.com comes first"

OR

Give me 10000 records from the table dbo.Emails but make shure everyone that contains "@horses.com" comes first, no matter how many there is.

BTW This is on an sql 2012 server.

Anyone??

Comment: Provide some sample data then it will be easier asses your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT TOP 10000 * 
FROM dbo.Emails 
ORDER BY IIF(Email LIKE '%@horses.com', 0, 1)
```

This assumes the email ends in '@horses.com', which isn't unreasonable. If you really want a `contains`-like function, add another `%` after the `.com`.

**Edit:** The `IIF` function is only available in sql server 2012 and later, for a more portable solution use `CASE WHEN Email LIKE '%@horses.com' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TOP 10000 * 
FROM dbo.Emails 
ORDER BY case when charindex('@horses.com', email) > 0 
              then 1
              else 2
         end,
         email
```

Comment: `case` is *much* preferred to `iif()` because it is ANSI standard, and even available in all versions of SQL Server.

Comment: Hi thank you also for you answer, to me it seems like this query is a bit slower than the one that uses iif... But it works fine (it should be "else 0" though)...

Comment: @Sandesjøl: No, it should be  `else 2` to put the `horses.com` on top

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 1,*  FROM dbo.Emails   where namn like '%@horses.com%'
  union
SELECT 2,*  FROM dbo.Emails   where namn not like '%@horses.com%'
order by 1
```